# android media not working

Tags: android

I create a raw folder within res folder and I past a mp3 song but in eclipse show error R.raw cannot be resolved and in console shows Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
my mp3 file name is MaidwiththeFlaxenHair.mp3  after the build the project the same is come

this the code

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.MaidwiththeFlaxenHair);
player.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use only lower-case letters:
`MaidwiththeFlaxenHair.mp3` -> `maidwiththeflaxenhair.mp3`